# Another instance with the key value is already being tracked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```cs
public JsonResult CreateOrder([FromBody]CustomerOrderModel orderModel)
{

    var customer = _customerService.GetCustomer(orderModel.customerid);
    var order = new OrderViewModel();

    order.Customer = customer;
    order.OrderPlacedOn = DateTime.Now;
    order.OrderForCustomer = customer.BusinessName;
    order.DiscountTotal = 0;
    order.TrackingCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    order.OrderTakenBy = _userManager.GetUserName(User);
    order.OrderChannel = orderModel.channel;
    order.CustomerNotes = orderModel.customernotes;
    order.isArchived = false;
    order.isRead = false;


    var orderitems = new List<OrderItemViewModel>();

    foreach (var item in orderModel.items)
    {
        var oi = new OrderItemViewModel();

        var product = _productService.GetProduct(item.pid);
        var price = (decimal)product.Price1;

        oi.ProductId = item.pid;
        oi.ProductCode = product.Code;
        oi.LineDiscount = 0;
        oi.LineTotal = price * item.qty;
        oi.VatTotal = price * (product.VatPercent / 100) * item.qty;
        oi.Quantity = item.qty;
        oi.Price = price;
        oi.PriceAfterCampaign = 0;
        oi.PriceAfterDiscounts = price * item.qty;
        oi.ProductName = product.Name;
        oi.VatPercentage = product.VatPercent;
        oi.CampaignInfo = string.Empty;
        oi.isAccepted = true;
        oi.isAcceptedNotes = string.Empty;

        orderitems.Add(oi);
    };

    order.OrderItems = orderitems;
    order.SubTotal = order.OrderItems.Sum(s => s.LineTotal);
    order.VatTotal = order.SubTotal = order.OrderItems.Sum(s => (decimal)s.VatTotal);
    order.GrandTotal = order.SubTotal = order.OrderItems.Sum(x => x.LineTotal + (decimal)x.VatTotal);

    _orderService.CreateOrder(order);

    return Json(order);
}
```

When the above method is executed I get an error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type
> 'Customer' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key
> value '{CustomerId: xx}' is already being tracked. When attaching
> existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given
> key value is attached.'

I cannot change anything at the repository level, in that case how can I resolve this?

Comment: Can you show when `order` is added in the context?

Comment: I am editing my question to include the whole method.

Comment: Is ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Yes aspnet5.0 and EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2

Comment: Can you show `CreateOrder`? I think the problem is from this method.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is related to the repository or ApplicationDbContext registered method, please check the code in the Startup.ConfigureServices method, and try to use the AddScoped() method to register the repository or ApplicationDbContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot change anything at repository level, you can handle the issue by setting the foreign key value instead of setting the parent reference.

Your `OrderViewModel` class should have a  `CustomerId` foreign key property. In your current code, replace -

```
order.Customer = customer;
```

with -

```
order.CustomerId = customer.Id;

// OR
order.CustomerId = orderModel.customerid;
```

If you don't already have the `CustomerId` property -

1. You need to add it, and also need to create a new migration and update the database.
2. EF is currently managing the foreign-key property as a `Shadow property` and has created a nullable foreign-key column `CustomerId` in your `Order` table. You can configure the foreign-key relation explicitly to create a non-nullable foreign key column -

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Customer)
            .WithMany(p=> p.Orders)  // if you don't have a Order collection in Customer model then use .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p=> p.CustomerId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DbContext is shared by `_customerService` and `_orderService`.
`_customerService` use the context to retrieve the customer, then the context track the customer entity.

Next `_orderService` in `CreateOrder` convert the model to entity. But the conversion generate a new customer entity instance with the same ID than the  customer entity instance already tracked above.

You need to fix `CreateOrder` to retrieve the customer from context instead of create new entity instance.

I know you write you can't change the repository level, but I assume that the repository level is bugged. I think `CreatOrder` create a new order and a new user. You can try to empty the tracked entity in the context, but then the context will suppose you want create a new user...